# No GUI with Centos 7 running on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, gnome, vnc, vnc-server

I am trying to get a GUI running on an AWS Centos 7 instance.  Tiger vnc seems to run fine and I can get connected with the tigervnc viewer.  However, all I get is a grey screen with 4 checkboxes in the upper right hand corner.

I installed Gnome and Server with GUI and I have tried changing my xstartup a hundred different ways, but I always get a grey screen.  See the screenshot.

How can I get the gnome gui to work over my vnc session?

thanks

[image]

Comment: https://medium.com/@jkimera5/installing-a-graphical-user-interface-gui-on-aws-ec2-linux-2-instance-and-accessing-it-over-a-1d96a16949dc

Comment: Thanks for the directions.  That's great.  But finally I figured out.  On Cpanel, I was running the user in a jailed root.  Once I opened up the access, it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you will get this issue when using cPanel and WHM if you have the user in a jailed root.  Open up the access and the full OS will load.

I would imagine that there is some way to work around this to keep a jailed root, but I am not a linux guru, so I don't know how to accomplish that.